# Prevent squid from changing http header

Tags: http, get, squid

I've a problem with squid Version 3.5.21 and I hope, someone could help me. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a proper solution..

When I'm accessing http://www.google.de via curl and without squid the http header looks like this:

```
curl -v http://www.google.de
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.de/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 172.217.17.67...
* Connected to www.google.de (172.217.17.67) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: www.google.de
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 17 Sep 2018 12:32:19 GMT
...
```

When using squid it looks like this:

```
curl -x http://127.0.0.1:3128 -v http://www.google.de
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.de/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3128 (#0)
> GET http://www.google.de/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
> Host: www.google.de
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 17 Sep 2018 12:19:22 GMT
...
```

The GET seems to be rewritten. Now some services in the internet blocking requests with the full URL in the GET request.

How can I configure squid (if it's possible) to let the GET untouched?

Thanks in advance!!

Regards, Matthias

Comment: AFAIU, it's *curl* which rewrites the request line because a proxy is configured. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#absolute-form

Comment: Not only curl. Also every other app which is talking to the Internet via Proxy. Thank you very much. That is not the solution for my problem as the Server in the Internet doesn’t accept these GET’s but it explains why it is like it is.

Comment: 1) Servers are expected to support the absolute form, 2) proxies are expected to rewrite the request line.

Comment: @JulianReschke I expect the same from servers just like its written in the RFC. Now I have to find a way to rewrite the request in squid as it doesn't do it automatically.